# ¿Como limpiar un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo un Formulario al cual le paso los datos desde otro formulario, pero al querer pasar otro dato el datagrid no se limpia y queda con los datos anteriores mas los que le acabe de ingresar

Este es mi código

```html
Form2 frm = new Form2();
                frm.ShowDialog();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in frm.dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        codigofactura.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        cliente.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        proveedor.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                        total.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                        int index = tblarticulo.Rows.Add();
                        tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["descripcion"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
                        tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["cantidad"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
                        tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["precio"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                        tblarticulo.Rows[index].Cells["valtotal"].Value = row.Cells[8].Value;
                    }
                }
```

¿Como puedo hacer que el datagrid se limpie cada vez que le regrese datos del formulario B al A?

De esta forma lleno el datagridview del formulario B del cual selecciono los datos y paso al formulario A

```html
 NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("mostrar", conexion);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes anular el dataSource

```
this.dataGridView.DataSource = null;
```

Luego borrar las filas:

```
this.dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

Ahora agregue los nuevos datos:

```
this.dataGridView.DataSource = this.GetNewValues();
```

Comment: Eso lo hago después del foreach?

Comment: En que momento necesitas cambiar los datos del grid?  supongo que seria antes del foreach , para que así puedas llenar de nuevo con la informacion

Comment: al momento de volver a cargar otros datos

Comment: para que recorra la tabla de donde voy a traer los datos

Comment: El foreach lo utilizas para cargar la informacion ? ya consultada ?

Comment: Entonces tienes que hacerlo antes

Comment: ok. voy  a probar para ver

Comment: me aparece un erro en **GetNewValues**

Comment: **GetNewValues** es tu informacón, debes cambiar esa variable por tu data con la consulta

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia...¿Cual vendría siendo mi data de consulta ?

Comment: No hagas esta parte , solo has las dos primeras y si te funciona edito la respuesta , `this.dataGridView.DataSource = this.GetNewValues();`

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: Con esas dos partes no me muestra nada en el datagrid

Comment: El dataSource entonces lo debes de llenar los nuevos datos que envias del formulario B